# How to apply any operation to the first element of each tuple

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

x= [("fjiwc", 1539), ("fejnd3", 1349), ("ABC123", 1.3878)]

How would I go about applying any operation to the first element of each tuple?

Comment: Are you using Python?  If so, you should iterate your list rather than using a pure regex.

Comment: Your question doesn’t depend on regular expressions at all. You basically need to know how to apply *any* operation to the first element of each tuple. That is what comprehensions and ˋmapˋ are there for.

Comment: Hi there. Yeah I realise now that is what my question should have been. I will have a look at comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: You can compare the iterator with regex as shown:

```py
import re

x = [("fjiwc", 1539, 1.0), ("fejnd3", 1349, 2.0), ("ettfd3", 1.3878, 1.0)]

result = [i for i in x if re.search(r"\d", i[0])]

print(result)
```

Which would result in giving this output:

```sh
$ python test.py
[('fejnd3', 1349, 2.0), ('ettfd3', 1.3878, 1.0)]
```

Comment: Hi there, I don't want to modify the tuples! I have edited the question as I wasn't clear enough. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know which tuples have a number in the first element:

```
import re

x= [("fjiwc", 1539, 1.0), ("fejnd3", 1349, 2.0), ("ettfd3", 1.3878, 1.0)]

for elem in x: # for each tuple in x
    if re.search(r"\d", elem[0]): # search the first element of the tuple
        print(elem[0]) # print the element
```

Prints:

```
fejnd3
ettfd3
```

If you just want to get a list of these elements, then use a *list comprehension*:

```
l = [elem[0] for elem in x if re.search(r"\d", elem[0])]
```

and you end up with:

```
['fejnd3', 'ettfd3']
```

Or if you want to filter the list of tuples based on whether the first element of the tuple contains a number, you just need a slight change to the above list comprehension:

```
l = [elem for elem in x if re.search(r"\d", elem[0])]
```

and you end up with:

```
[('fejnd3', 1349, 2.0), ('ettfd3', 1.3878, 1.0)]
```